# Criar um menu "accordion" apenas com CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3

Menus no estilo *accordion* (sanfona) são úteis para economizar espaço, já que você só abre as partes com o conteúdo que você precisa.

> [image: Exemplo de menu sanfona]
>   <sup>Exemplo de menu estilo *accordion.*</sup>

Mas todos esses menus geralmente utilizam JavaScript para fazer a funcionalidade de "contrair" e "expandir" os subitens. É possível criar esse tipo de funcionalidade **apenas com CSS**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> "É possível criar esse tipo de funcionalidade **apenas com CSS**?"

Sim. Você pode conseguir este efeito com CSS usando o atributo HTML `tabindex`.

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu-sanfona">
    <li tabindex="0">Item 1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1.1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="1">Item 2
        <ul>
            <li>Item 2.1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

E o CSS:

```
.menu-sanfona li ul{
    display:none;
}
.menu-sanfona li:focus ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Exemplo mais completo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/GBhJ7/)**

O que o código faz é usar o atributo `tabindex` para tornar os elementos `li` passíveis de foco, e então com CSS é definido que quando o `li` estiver com foco, o `ul` filho dele fica visível.

Apesar desta solução ser interessante por não usar JavaScript, ela fica um pouco limitada, já que o elemento só fica aberto enquanto está com foco, ou seja, caso você clique em algum `input` ou outro item que possua foco, o menu se fecharia.

Comment: muito bom! Usando css3 da para fazer até efeito de deslizamento lento, deixe essa opção para os demais obterem um conhecimento a mais!!

Comment: Uma dúvida por que quando insiro um link ele fecha o quadrado e não é redirecionado para a pág? Ótima dica!
:)